# Is there a nice analytic criterion when does three normals of three points on the same conic section meet at the same point?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Is there a nice analytic criterion when does three normals of three points on the same conic section meet at the same point?

For parabola we have an answer here: [3 normals on a parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592651/3-normals-on-a-parabola?rq=1)

Also, is there an Euclidian geometry criterion?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2751265/248217.

Comment: This could be of help for an ellipse: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2553266/ellipse-concurrency-of-normals

Comment: do u have any combinatorics questions?

Comment: @mathworker21 Yeah sure, what am I doing wrong here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3590204/anna-stands-at-a0-0-and-eve-at-b5-3-what-is-the-maximum-probability-th

Comment: @Aqua what level of education are you in?

Comment: highschool ....@mathworker21

Comment: @mathworker21 "I recently dropped out of math grad school. I am now an employee at Infowars." What do you do there? And why did you dropped?

Comment: @Aqua Currently a mix of video editing and journalism. I dropped out because I thought I could make a bigger impact on the world through journalism. I understand wanting to do math for the fun of it, but I wanted to make a difference in the world.

Comment: But you will be still active here? @mathworker21

Comment: @Aqua yup ${}{}{}{}$